# How/why is this function legal in OCaml? Also, how would I go about checking if statements like this one are legal in the future?

Tags: string, ocaml, let

I'm not sure how to properly go through this function and determine its type. I typed it into an OCaml top level and the output is "hello world" but I do not know why. Could someone please explain how they determined the final output? Thanks!

```
 let f y =  
    let z = (let x = 5 in y * x) + y in "hello" in (f 7) ^ " world"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the entire thing is based on the OCaml construct `let a = b in c`. If you match up the `let` and `in` pairs, you can see the structure of the expression.

```
let f y =
    let z = (let x = 5 in y * x) + y
    in "hello"
in (f 7) ^ " world"
```

Essentially `f` is a function that does some useless computation then returns "hello".

**Update**

This code has two slightly different uses of `let a = b in c`. Maybe it will be clearer to explain them separately.

The following:

```
let y = expr1 in expr2
```

defines a new name `y` with the value given by `expr`. The name `y` can then be used in `expr2`.

The following:

```
let f x = expr1 in expr2
```

defines a function `f`. The definition `expr1` will usually use the argument `x` to calculate an interesting value. Then the function `f` can be called in `expr2`.

Your code has two instances of the first construct (defining values `z` and `x`), and one of the second construct (defining function `f`).

Comment: What does the "in" keyword do? Im new to ocaml so correct me if I am wrong, but to me, the in keyword takes "hello"as a starting input of the function z

Comment: The `in` keyword matches a previous `let` keyword. There is no function `z`, z is just a value.

Answer (score 1):

This function is specially obfuscated, so lets move carefully over the reduction steps:

```
let f y =  
    let z = (let x = 5 in y * x) + y in "hello" in (f 7) ^ " world"

==>

let f y = 
    let z = y * 5 + y in "hello" in (f 7) ^ " world"

==>

let f y = 
    let z = y * 5 + y in "hello" in (f 7) ^ " world"
```

At this point is obvious, that `z` is unused in function `f`, let's remove it:

```
let f y = "hello" in (f 7) ^ " world"
```

We can see, that actually we have the "function" `f`, that always returns "hello":

```
let f y = "hello"
```

That is defined in the scope of the expression `(f 7) ^ " world"`. `f 7` is evaluated to `"hello"`, and we have `"hello world"`.

The

```
let <name> = <expr-1> in <expr-2>
```

has the following rules of evaluation:

1. evaluate `<expr-1>`
2. substitute each free occurrences of `<name>` in `<expr-2>` with `<expr-1>`
3. evaluate `<expr-2>`